# ON taylor coefficients for a function with singularities

Tags: taylor-expansion

we know Taylor series coefficients are given by

$$ a(n)= \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}f(0) $$

then my question is if we want the taylor series involving the term $ 1/x$

could i use the limit $$ a(-1)= \frac{1}{\Gamma(-1)}\frac{d^{-1}}{dx^{-1}}f(0)$$

taking the limit of this expression as $ x--> 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some function with a simple pole at $0$, it is sufficient to find the limit $a(-1)=\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x)$. If there are poles of higher order, you need to start with the highest order pole. If you have a highest-order pole $x^{-n}$, we get that $a(-n)=
lim_{n\to 0}x^nf(x)$. Then, remove the pole by subtracting $\frac{a(-n)}{x^n}$ from $f$ and repeat the process.